# Navigate to a tab of a website based on title name in VBA

Tags: javascript, html, vba, web-scraping

I am trying to navigate to another tab shown in the html code below from my current tab in VBA.

```html
<div title="0274 AP INVOICES SAP" data-bind="text: Name, attr: { title: Name }">0274 AP INVOICES SAP</div>
```

I tried the following:

```
ie.document.querySelector("[title*=AP INVOICES SAP].menu-row active-route").Click
```

but this gave me the "Method 'querySelector' of object 'JScriptTypeInfo' failed" error, and I also tried the following:

```
ie.document.querySelector("div[data-bind*='0274 AP INVOICES SAP']").Click
```

but this gave me the "Object required" error.

What should I do to navigate to this tab properly? Please let me know if you need more information

Comment: Looks like the `querySelector` argument is malformed in the first attempt, and well-formed but returning an array (?) in the second one; assuming `querySelector` returns an array, then you need to pick a subscript to invoke the `Click` member against, e.g. `ie.document.querySelector("div[data-bind*='0274 AP INVOICES SAP']")(0).Click`

Answer (score 0):

You have half the answer (syntax wise) in each of your two lines.

You need

```
ie.document.querySelector("[title='0274 AP INVOICES SAP']").click
```

Assuming a proper page load wait has happened before and that this title = value combination is either unique and/or you want the first; that it is not dynamic and that it is the correct target for the click event.

Due to the spaces in the value string you need to use single quotes around the it. Also, after the attribute selector you should not be using class selectors which aren't part of the target element.

If you continue to get a JScriptTypeInfo error, which I have seen before with pages using `knockoutjs`, you need to either resort to MS ScriptControl and a lot more code (on a 32 bit system) - which I don't recommend, or switch to using a getElement(s) by method where this problem shouldn't occur. You are ending up with an array like object that VBA is calling JSCriptTypeInfo and if you inspect it you will mostly likely see a string denoting an array of objects (nodes) which come, I suspect, from a default member call.